# ProcessStartInfo .WaitForExit() is not working properly

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

So, I have this code to call a batch file.

```
        If System.IO.File.Exists(FSourceFile) Then
            Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo(batchFileLoc + batchFileName)
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            psi.UseShellExecute = False
            Dim myProcess As Process = Process.Start(psi)
            Dim output As String = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
            myProcess.WaitForExit(180000)
            If (myProcess.HasExited) Then
                Throw New Exception("FTP failed due to time-out. Please check the connectivity to FTP server.")
            End If
            FTPFile = "Success"
        End If
```

I want that "myProcess" should exit if the batch file execution is not completed within 3mins. But even when the batch file execution gets completed within less than 2 seconds, 
     myProcess.HasExited
returns True.
If I put 2000 instead of 180000, the process works fine.
What is that is going wrong here?

Comment: This is confusing.  Maybe you want to change If (myProcess.HasExited) Then to If Not myProcess.HasExited Then.

Comment: @dbasnett I want to check whether the batch file is running properly or not. So I am using If (myProcess.HasExited). The process should be complete within 3mins, if not, it should exit and show error.

Comment: You just have the test backwards.  It should be **Not** myProcess.HasExited.  Use the return value of WaitForExit() instead.

Comment: yes I see my stupidity. Thnx both

Comment: Take a look at the answer which uses the WaitForExit.

Answer (score 1):

myProcess.HasExited just tells you if the process exited or not. If you're interested if process exited due to timeout you should use

```
If Not myProcess.WaitForExit(180000) Then
    Throw New Exception("FTP failed due to time-out. Please check the connectivity to FTP server.")
End If
```